# After episode 3 of season 8, how many dragons do the allies have?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the E03 S08 of Game of Thrones, the two living dragons, respectively ridden by Deanerys and Jon, fight against the *dead* dragon, ridden by the Night King.

During the fight, Jon's dragon happens to fall down to the ground. When I watched the episode, I supposed the dragon was dead.

At the end of the episode, a *dead* dragon come into Winterfell to breathe blue fire everywhere. Is it the first *dead* dragon the Night king was riding, or is it Jon's dragon, killed during the dragons fight, who came back to life after the Night King summoned all the dead on the battlefield ?

And finally, how many dragons do we have left ?

Answer (score 2):

It's the first dead dragon the Night king was riding, because his neck is perforated. And during the fight we saw Jon's dragon hurt the other one.